# PySpark runs in YARN client mode but fails in cluster mode for "User did not initialize spark context!"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

- standard dataproc image 2.0
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Hadoop 3.2
- Spark 3.1

I am testing to run a very simple script on dataproc pyspark cluster:

testing_dep.py

```
import os
os.listdir('./')
```

I can run testing_dep.py in a client mode (default on dataproc) just fine:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark ./testing_dep.py --cluster=pyspark-monsoon --region=us-central1
```

But, when I try to run the same job in cluster mode I get error:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark ./testing_dep.py --cluster=pyspark-monsoon --region=us-central1 --properties=spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
```

error logs:

```
Job [417443357bcd43f99ee3dc60f4e3bfea] submitted.
Waiting for job output...
22/01/12 05:32:20 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at monsoon-testing-m/10.128.15.236:8032
22/01/12 05:32:20 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at monsoon-testing-m/10.128.15.236:10200
22/01/12 05:32:22 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
22/01/12 05:32:22 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
22/01/12 05:32:24 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1641965080466_0001
22/01/12 05:32:42 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: Application application_1641965080466_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1641965080466_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 13
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2022-01-12 05:32:42.154]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1641965080466_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 13

[2022-01-12 05:32:42.203]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
22/01/12 05:32:40 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context!
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:899)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:898)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)


[2022-01-12 05:32:42.203]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
22/01/12 05:32:40 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context!
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:899)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:898)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://monsoon-testing-m:8188/applicationhistory/app/application_1641965080466_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1641965080466_0001 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1634)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pyspark) Job [417443357bcd43f99ee3dc60f4e3bfea] failed with error:
Google Cloud Dataproc Agent reports job failure. If logs are available, they can be found at:
https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/jobs/417443357bcd43f99ee3dc60f4e3bfea?project=monsoon-credittech&region=us-central1
gcloud dataproc jobs wait '417443357bcd43f99ee3dc60f4e3bfea' --region 'us-central1' --project 'monsoon-credittech'
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/64632294-3e9b-4c55-af8a-075fc7d6f412/jobs/417443357bcd43f99ee3dc60f4e3bfea/
gs://monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/64632294-3e9b-4c55-af8a-075fc7d6f412/jobs/417443357bcd43f99ee3dc60f4e3bfea/driveroutput
```

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong and why this code is failing?

Comment: Could it be that that abz.zip must be in a location that is reachable from all cluster nodes? You provide only a relative location, that is valid only on your local machine.

Comment: But, my code is not dependent upon abc.zip. It just prints the contents of the working directory.

Comment: I assume that does not matter since the archives are distributed before the python code is executed. Does the code work without the archives flag?

Comment: No. But, I restarted my cluster and the error has changed. Beats me what is happening. I am updating the question to show the error. The code is failing with or without --archives in cluster mode

Comment: Can you please take a look?

Comment: I have looked more into this and this has nothing to do with ```--archives``` and changing the spark configuration. I create a simple 3 nodes vanilla cluster with standard dataproc image and ```os.listdir()``` fails in cluster mode. Updating the question with that so there isn't much to follow for anyone landing here

Comment: My next guess :) - your code might actually have been executed, but you don't see it (1) has no print-statement and (2) you do not see the stdout in cluster-mode because your driver code is executed not on your local machine, but in some other cluster node. The error message complains about not starting a spark session, but that might be some standard error when no SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate() statement is there.

Comment: Should I not get that error in the case of client mode as well if that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is expected when running Spark in YARN cluster mode but the job doesn't create Spark context. See the source code of [ApplicationMaster.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.0/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala#L525).

To avoid this error, you need to create a SparkContext or SparkSession, e.g.:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .appName('MySparkApp') \
                    .getOrCreate()
```

Client mode doesn't go through the same code path and doesn't have a similar check.

Comment: Yes this solved the issue. It is weird that I do not get the error even when I create the ```SparkSession``` after the ```os.listdir()``` part of the code. I placed my ```SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() ``` at the end of the script and it still worked.